# issue with jquery smooth scroll spy not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menus bars in website this is a single page website. When user click on a memu scrollspy event gets activated through jquery. Till Here it is working well but when i switch to mobile view their is not smooth scrollspy effect.

I HAVE WRITTEN WITH CUSTOM CSS

Here is the HTML CODE

```
 <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 nav-wrapper" id="myNavbar">

                        <!-- Nav Start -->
                        <nav class="navbar1">
                            <ul class="sf-menu" id="menu">
                                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#practise_area">Practice Areas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>                                 
                                <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>                                   
                                <li><a href="#career">Careers</a></li>                                  
                                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <!-- Nav End -->

                    </div>
```

Here is the Jquery Script

```
<script>
$('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar1", offset: 50});
    
        $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event){
            if(this.hash != ""){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            
            //store hash
            var hash =  this.hash;
            
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 500, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

HERE IS THE CSS CODE

### THE CSS CODE IS VERY LONG SO I HAVE FILTERED HERE

```
    header .nav-wrapper {
        float: right;
    }
    header .nav-wrapper ul {
        float: right;
    }
    
    .sf-menu .menu-description {
        display: none;
    }
    
    sf-menu li a {
        padding: 10px 18px;
    }
    
    .sf-menu li li a {
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    
    .sf-menu > li {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .sf-menu > li {
        margin-top: 0;
        height: 60px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
    
    .sf-menu {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .sf-menu ul {
        box-shadow: none;
        border-top: 0;
    }
    .sf-menu a {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .sf-menu li {
        text-transform: none;
        background: none;
    }
```

Here is the desktop view
[image: Desktop View]

Here is the mobile View

[image: Mobile View]

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: add css code...

Comment: @Mr_Pandya i have updated answere. but i think the issue is more related to `jquery`